# Upgrade Mongo DB Error - "Unsupported WiredTiger file version"

Tags: mongodb

I'm having the exact same issue described [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-35271), but with diferent versions:

1. I have a 3.4.7 MongoDB database with data **I can't lose**.
2. I upgraded to 3.6.9
3. Set FCV to "3.6"
4. I upgraded to 4.0.20
5. When I try to start server I got this error

`2020-01-30T14:17:19.932-0500 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1580411839:932626][32464:0x7f126518da40], connection: __log_open_verify, 1028: Version incompatibility detected: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build requires a maximum version of 2, and the file is version 3: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error`

If I delete the data directory and start MongoDB 4.0.10 it works, but I can't add it to the 3.6 replicaSet I have with the other nodes to sync and recover data. So if I follow this process in all nodes I will finish losing all my data.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I got to add the instance to the replicaSet. The reason why it was not being added was due to the change of the protocolVersion was not effective. The solution to this was a restart of the secondaries, stepdown of the primary and restart of the primary (in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/927502/364776) is the detail of the process)

After adding the instance to the replicaSet the data was synced automatically.

Comment: There are multiple ways to upgrade a replica set installation.  One method is to upgrade in place - upgrade binaries to 3.6, then upgrade FCV to 3.6, then stablize, then repeat for version 4.0.  Another method is to throw away the secondaries, upgrade the primary  then add new secondaries and allow initial sync to have them replicate.  The in place upgrade - AKA rolling upgrade - allows constant uptime.  The second method incurs much more risk because there are no secondaries during the upgrade and a server failure could turn catastrophic.  Rolling upgrades are recommended.